# ASP.NET MVC Windows Azure organization authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to configure the organization authentication in an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 RC.
After filling the data in the create project dialog, like Microsoft instructed in their tutorials, I'm getting an error which says that the configure failed.
I've tried to do so as well in Visual Studio 2012 using the identity addon.

Maybe it's related to Windows Azure AD?

Here is the error that I'm getting:
[image: Describe image]

Hopes that someone knows how to fix that issue. Thanks for any help and suggestion!

Comment: It regularly happens to me too. Probably it needs a fix. If you try running the web in these conditions you get an argument null exception. You can try fixing this by manually adding to web.config app settings the entry <add key="ida:Tenant" value="YOURTENANTNAME"/>. Get the tenant name under Azure portal, directory, domain (it's the string before the @onmicrosoft.com ending). Dunno if this is enough anyway, I did not try yet. Anyone having more luck?

Comment: No luck here... Will update you if I'll be able to fix it... Did somebody solved that?

Comment: This issue was resolved with VS 2013 Update 3.  You can now use a MS account instead of an org account.  [Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/use-a-microsoft-account-to-create-web-apps-protected-by-azure-ad-with-vs2013-update-3.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but today I found a workaround that I'd like to share.

It seems like we can't use Microsoft Account when we're using WAAD.

So:

1. Create a WAAD.
2. Add an administrator

   - Choose local directory account, **not Microsoft Account**.
   - Grant this account Global Administrator permissions.
3. Open Visual Studio and create a new web based project.
4. Choose in authentication the "Organization Accounts".
5. Specify your WAAD URL (e.g. "foo@onmicrosoft.com").
6. When you're required to insert your user and password, use the local account username and password. for example ("oz@foo.onmicrosoft.com").

This will allow you to pass the error.

***Edit:***
Microsoft published a post that referred to this problem and show the solution (the one I described above). http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/12/11/setting-up-an-asp-net-project-with-organizational-authentication-requires-an-organizational-account/

Answer (score 0):

I would check for two things:

- The account used to login to Windows Azure while has Global Admin role in AAD
- App ID URI specified in the project creation dialog is valid. Valid App ID URI for domain mydomain.onmicrosoft.com has format https://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/uniqueUri. Note that you can leave this field blank and the tool will automatically pick the correct App ID URI for you.

If these two things don't help, I would encourage you to run DebugView (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) in the background while trying to create a similar project and you can see the actual error message in the trace in DebugView.

Comment: Thanks! I made sure that the account does have global admin role and that the URL is valid but still no luck. Fortunately, Microsoft released the stable version of Visual Studio 2013 so we can check if they fixed it. I'll keep you updated as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

In follow up to OzB:

Once you've setup the user in AAD as per OzB's account,
note that you must also then go to "Settings" in Azure and add that account as an administrator of the Azure subscription, otherwise you can't upload the website itself.